# Cannot find DavWWWRoot file

Tags: sharepoint

I have an Excel File that's held on a SharePoint site and when I go to it's DavWWWRoot path the excel file is unable to be opened. Any Idea as to why this is happening?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoTVR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could check that whether other files in the same path could be accessed.

If the whole DavWWWRoot is not accessible, We need to restart the server and map network drive again, according to the error, first we need to add the web site to your trusted site and select the option to logon automatically in IE settings > Internet Options:

[image]

[image]

Finally, remember to uncheck the option in IE settings > Internet Options > General:

[image]

As a result, if you map network drive again, it will work normally:
[image]

you could also refer to this similar case:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/762616/win-10-mapped-drive-to-sharepoint-directory-with.html